# How to get the results to only display the data with a certain label on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a rudimentary recipe searching app in React, the data received from the API is displayed in recipe cards in the Recipe component. I want to add buttons which once click filter the results to display the recipes cards with the Vegan healthLabel.

This is the App component which interacts with the API. I'm stuck on how to get the results to only display the data with a certain label on click.

```
    const App = () =>
  const APP_ID = '072f4029';
  const APP_KEY = '1e1f9dc0b5c22bdd26363da4bbaa74b8';

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, [query])


  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}&from=0&to=12`)
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes(data.hits);
  }

  const updateSearch = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  }

  const getSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
    setSearch('');
  }




  const props = useSpring({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0 } })

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className="header">
        <div className="logo">
          <img className="knife" src={logo} alt="Logo" />
          <h1>Recipe Finder</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="search-form">
        <InputGroup>
          <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
            <InputGroupText><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} /></InputGroupText>
          </InputGroupAddon>
          <Input className="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search for recipe..." value={search} onChange={updateSearch} />
        </InputGroup>
        <Button color="primary" size="sm" className="search-button" type="submit">Search</Button>
      </form>
      <UncontrolledAlert className="alert" color="info">
        <a href="https://www.sambailey.dev">sambailey.dev</a>
      </UncontrolledAlert>
      <div style={props} className="recipes">
        {recipes.map(recipe => (
          <Recipe
            key={recipe.recipe.label}
            title={recipe.recipe.label}
            theUrl={recipe.recipe.url}
            image={recipe.recipe.image}
            ingredients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
            source={recipe.recipe.source}
            healthLabels={recipe.recipe.healthLabels}
            servings={recipe.recipe.yield} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is the Recipe card component

```js
const Recipe = ({ title, theUrl, image, ingredients, source, healthLabels, servings, deleteRecipe }) => {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

    const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);
    const down = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSortDown} />
    const zoom = <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={toggle} className={style.maximise} icon={faSearchPlus} />
    const Heart = styled(Checkbox)({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 1,
        right: 1,
    });

    return (
        <div className={style.recipe}>
            <Heart className={style.heart} icon={<FavoriteBorder />} checkedIcon={<Favorite />} name="checkedH" />
            <div className={style.top}>
                <h6>{title}</h6>
                <Badge className={style.badge} color="primary">{source}</Badge>
                <p>Serves: <Badge color="primary" pill>{servings}</Badge></p>
                <div className={style.imageContainer}>
                    <img onClick={toggle} src={image} alt='food' />
                    {zoom}
                </div>
                <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
                    <img src={image} alt="" className={style.maxi} />
                </Modal>
            </div>
            <ol className={style.allergens}>
                {healthLabels.map(healthLabel => (
                    <li>{healthLabel}</li>
                ))}
            </ol>
            <div className={style.ingr}>
                <p className={style.inghead} id="toggler">Ingredients <Badge color="secondary">{ingredients.length}</Badge> {down}</p>
                <UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggler">
                    <ol id="myol">
                        {ingredients.map(ingredient => (
                            <li className={style.customList}>{ingredient.text}</li>
                        ))}
                    </ol>
                </UncontrolledCollapse>
                <Button className={style.button} outline color="primary" size="sm" href={theUrl} target="_blank">Method</Button>
            </div>
            <div className={style.info}>
                <div className={style.share}>
                    <WhatsappShareButton url={theUrl}><WhatsappIcon round={true} size={20} /></WhatsappShareButton>
                    <FacebookShareButton url={theUrl}><FacebookIcon round={true} size={20} /></FacebookShareButton>
                    <EmailShareButton url={theUrl}><EmailIcon round={true} size={20} /></EmailShareButton>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >


    );
}

export default Recipe;
```

Comment: Will the clicking of the label trigger another fetch from the API, with only results that belong to that label? Or do you want to filter the current list (without another fetch)?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear, I want to trigger another fetch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` is already dependent on the `query` property. To trigger a new fetch, you could set the state of the `query` parameter to the one you want to fetch:

label onclick pseudocode:

```js
export default function Recipe({ onLabelClick, label }) {
  return (
    <div onClick={onLabelClick}>
      {label}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can then load a Recipe like so:

```js
<Recipe 
  onLabelClick={() => setQuery("what you want your new query to be")
  label={recipe.recipe.label}
/>
```

When clicked, the `query` property will be updated and the `useEffect` will be triggered as a result. This will lead to a new fetch!

[EDIT] The OP asked also for an example on how to filter already loaded recipes:

```js
// Let's assume a recipe has a property "title"
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
const [filteredRecipes, setFilteredRecipes] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (filter) {
    const newFilteredRecipes = recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.title.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()));
    setFilteredRecipes(newFilteredRecipes);
  }
}, [recipes, filter]);

return (
  <>
  {filteredRecipes.map((recipe, index) => {
    return <Recipe 
        key={index}
        onLabelClick={() => setQuery("what you want your new query to be")
        label={recipe.recipe.label}
      />
    }
  }
  </>
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would also like the filter the current results as you mentioned previously.

Comment: You can simply use a `filter` property (`const [filter, setFilter] = useState('')`), that is used to filter the list of `Recipe`!

Comment: Sure, I've added an example

Comment: Where would the return of the filtered recipe cards go in relation to the App component?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't really understand what you are asking. Maybe it's better to open a new question?